# Import Json to Google Sheets automitcally and manually

Tags: python, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I use Appscript of google sheets to import json data into Google Sheets
I looked at this github link : [import_json_appsscript.js][1]
and I have the API here of ticketmaster.com : https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?size=1&apikey=xxxxxxx

Should I use the code of github link all of it into Appsscript?
[1]: https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

2- How can I do this in automating way with Python or Javascript
that I have the json data then create Google Sheets file Automatically then represent the data in it.

```
 var url = "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?size=1&apikey=xxxxxxx";
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log("Events");
        }
    };

xhr.send();
```

Comment: It depends upon the structure of the data.  So you either need some AI program to figure out what you have or you need to use the matter between your ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the gspread library for python. Take a look at the docs here: https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/#example-usage. Once you have it all set up the below code should work for uploading a json

```
import json
import gspread
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

# connect to your google sheet
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('key.json', scopes=scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("spreadsheet name").sheet1

# You can load a json file here, just using some sample data
x =  '{ "receiver_email_1":6, "receiver_email_2":8, "receiver_email_3":10 }'
y = json.loads(x)

result = []
for key in y:
    result.append([key,y[key]])

wks.update('A1', result)
```

Comment: May I ask what are requiered dependencies to use this script with python should I install FLask or Django due to this will require UI and can not be done through command lines.

Comment: You should be able to save this to a .py file and run it? I might be misunderstanding your question, have you been exclusively using the interactive shell? You can use the requests library to query the api. @Jack

Comment: Thanks it works, but I just have a problem with appending I guess it a key problem
the json data start like this `{'_embedded': {'events': [{'name': 'Paul McCartney', 'type': 'event', 'id': 'Z7r9jZ1Ad8ekd', 'test': ` etc..... 
So how to append this kind of data in the array then update the sheet with the array.